# Fetching owner details in Azure resources created an year ago

Tags: list, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, kql, azure-resource-graph

I tried to fetch details of resource owners created an year ago using powershell script but iam getting errors. Is it possible to create one?

This is the code I used:

```
foreach ($resource in $resources) { 
    $createdBy = $resource.Properties.createdBy 
    if ($createdBy -and $createdBy.userPrincipalName) { 
        $ownerDetails = Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName $createdBy.userPrincipalName 
        Write-Host "Resource: $($resource.Name), Created by: $($ownerDetails.DisplayName) - $($ownerDetails.UserPrincipalName)" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can yo edit the question and provide both the code and the error you are getting?

Comment: sure , I tried using the below power shell script to get the ownerdetails of resources

Comment: its too long to keep in comment

Comment: foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    $createdBy = $resource.Properties.createdBy
    if ($createdBy -and $createdBy.userPrincipalName) {
        $ownerDetails = Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName $createdBy.userPrincipalName
        Write-Host "Resource: $($resource.Name), Created by: $($ownerDetails.DisplayName) - $($ownerDetails.UserPrincipalName)"
    } is the logic i used

Comment: You should not add it as a comment but to the question :-)
What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell script you used is looking good to me to achieve your requirement. But it might not work as expected if the `creationdate/time` doesn't contain the proper information about the owner identity.

Instead use `createdby` to retrieve the exact requirement as shown below.

*Efficient script:*

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddYears(-1)
$resource = Get-AzResource | Where-Object { $_.Properties.createdTime -lt $date }

foreach ($res in $resource) {
    Write-Output "ResourceID: $($res.ResourceId), Createdby: $($res.Properties.CreatedBy)"
}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use the [`Get-AzLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azlog?view=azps-0.10.0) command to get the above needed information which is detailed below.

```
$startTime = (Get-Date).AddYears(-1)
$endTime = Get-Date
$logs = Get-AzLog -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime -Status "Started" -Resourceprovider "Microsoft.Resources/deployments"
foreach ($log in $logs) {
    $user = $log.Claims["http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"]
    if ($user) {
        $info = Get-AzADUser -ObjectId $user
        Write-Host "Resourceinfo:$($log.ResourceId), Created by: $($info.DisplayName) - $(info.UserPrincipalName)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Get-AzLog : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: The start time cannot be more than 90 days in the past., Code: BadRequest, Status 
code:BadRequest, Reason phrase: Bad Request
At line:14 char:9
+ $logs = Get-AzLog -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime -Status "St ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzActivityLog], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Events.GetAzureRmLogCommand

Comment: Have you tried with the first script? @Anjumaara

Comment: `Get-AzLog` is not taking the time period more than 90 days by default. Have you tried the other script which I provided. @Anjumaara

Comment: $res.Properties.CreatedBy always be null at my side. help.

Comment: $res is resource you meant? @wenbo

Comment: I mean I can not get the CreatedBy property. as in your pic, your createdBy also empty.